# Search field does not have placeholder text on Ask Ubuntu

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, top-bar

I have the dubious privilege of having early access to the new top bar on Ask Ubuntu since I am a moderator there. The search field there is just a grayed out box with nothing to indicate that it is in any way functional, let alone the way to search:

[image: AU top bar]

On other sites, it works as expected: there's at least some text to indicate that you can use this gray blob for searching:

1. Unix & Linux:

   [image: U&L top bar]
2. Bioinformatics

   [image: Bioinformatics top bar]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thanks for the report! This is now fixed:

[image: Ask Ubuntu header]

I was using an over-eager check for "Is this a Q&A site?" which checked if the site's hostname ended in "stackexchange.com", so thank you so much for spotting this before it went live everywhere :)